# how to translate the contact form7 alarm language?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, polylang

Receive a alarm when I enter an error message, my website is multilingual, but contact form 7 only show the chinese alarm message, how to fix this?[just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2i04.png)

i used translation tool is "polylang"

Thanks

Comment: you have to make a form for each language.

Comment: how to do? for example: [mysite]/en/ version, but the form alarm message still is chinese.......

Comment: update: i find the reason, the theme control my contact form 7, but i don't know how to find the related source file